# SQLite : insert multiple value (select from) with insert specified value

Tags: sql, sqlite

i'm trying to make sqlite query that can insert multiple values , here's my query that i try :

```
    insert into table1(idy_table1,idx_table1) 
    values ('1',                               //specified value insert to idy_table1                               
    (select id_table2 from table2))            //insert value from select id_table2
```

i'm having some trouble, it just only insert one value,

and my question is how to make a proper query? so i can make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The VALUES clause always adds one row.
(Except when you're using multiple tuples, but this does not work with queries.)

The easiest way to add multiple rows from a query is to use the [SELECT form](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) of the INSERT statement:

```
INSERT INTO Table1(idy_table1, idx_table1)
SELECT '1', id_table2 FROM table2;
```